# Shall we use a color name like"grey" instead "setBackground(new Color(107, 106, 104));"?

Tags: java

Shall we use a color name like"grey" instead "Color(107, 106, 104)" ?
My code returning some error like:

```
* MessageFrame2.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : constructor Color(java.awt.Color)
location: class java.awt.Color
setBackground(new Color(Color.grey));*
```

Comment: The Color constants will, generally, give you more consistent result and are far easier to remember.  You're also not creating lots of potentially, short lived objects.  `Color.GRAY` will be the same instance everywhere you use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the symbol is `Color.gray`.

Answer (score 3):

Just use

```
setBackground(Color.gray);
```

Comment: it returns the following Error:  cannot find symbol

Comment: Because you are calling the constructor of an instance of Color. The integer values of the colors are static fields in color. Access them as @Rebelek mentions above.

Answer (score 1):

All constants defined in `Color` class are `Color` objects themselves. So you can directly use

```
setBackground(Color.GRAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is  not `Color.grey`  it is `Color.gray`
and you can directly set it with out creating any object.
and the constant define in Color for gray is below

```
public final static Color gray      = new Color(128, 128, 128);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Color.gray instead of Color.grey have a look here --> http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/~daeron/docs/apidocs/java.awt.Color.html

Comment: yep... (Color.gray) works fine for me.. Thanks for the help guys  @Sri harsha Chilakapati